# The or no article

Tags: articles, zero-article

Why not put the article for example in this sentence?

> ***The*** man of the match

Comment: That is not a complete sentence. Do you have the whole sentence so there's better context?

Comment: @Mixolydian, I mean, when announces the best player of the match. Usually said without the article.

Comment: If you [edit] your question to add more detail and explain what you found when you looked for an answer before posting we should be able to take it off hold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With so little context, there's no way to know whether the sentence needs that article. If you said something like "The man of the match is John", then that would require the article. However, one might say "I'll be/win man of the match next time!", and one doesn't need the article then.